# How to prevent tinyMCE accepting normal image tags while allowing data images

Tags: tinymce

Is there some way of configuring tinyMCE so that data images are allowed while relative or absolute url images are prevented?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the url_convertercallback http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:urlconverter_callback